# bootstrap 4: dropdown, nav-pills and seperate link together in horizontal line

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

I have an `html` file, which displays in Firefox as:
[image: Screenshot]

Problem is, I want to have everything in **one single horizontal** row next to each other:

- the label `Dropdown`,
- the dropdown box itself,
- the bootstrap `nav-pills` menu and
- the separate link.

My code is (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/162055/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let menus = ['Menu1', 'Menu2', 'Menu3'];
  $('header ul').addClass("nav nav-pills");
  for (let m of menus) {
    $('header ul').append(`<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-value="${m}" data-toggle="pill" href="#">${m}</a>
                        </li>`);
  }
  $('header a').first().addClass('active');
  $('header a').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dd1">Dropdown:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="dd1">
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <ul></ul>
    <a href="#">Seperate Link</a>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried

- add css `style="display:inline-block"` to `<div>`, `<ul>` and `<a>` elements
- use a `bootstrap grid` as described in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

But nothing worked so far.

Comment: Please provide fiddle link

Comment: here: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/162055/ hope it works, I did not create an account in order to set up the example. Let me know if there are any problems with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class="row"` to wrap `div` and wrap `divs` in `col-*`

Learn here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```js
        $(document).ready( function(){
            let menus = ['Menu1', 'Menu2', 'Menu3'];
            $('header ul').addClass("nav nav-pills");
            for (let m of menus) {
                $('header ul').append(`<li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-value="${m}" data-toggle="pill" href="#">${m}</a>
                    </li>`
                );
            }
            $('header a').first().addClass('active');
            $('header a').click(function(){
                console.log($(this).data('value'));
            });
        });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<header>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-5">
      <label for="dd1  col-form-label" >Dropdown:</label>
      <select class="form-control d-inline-block col-8" id="dd1">
        <option>Value1</option>
        <option>Value2</option>
      </select>
    </div> 
       
  <div class="col-7 d-flex">
    <div class="col-9 p-0">
      <ul></ul>
     </div> 
    <div class="col-3 pt-2"> 
     <a href="#">Link</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div> 
       
</header>
```